# When a subspace $B$ of $A$ is separable if $A$ is separable?

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory

I'm stuck to show that a certain subset (topological subspace) of a vector space $E$ is separable, since $E$ is separable. More precisely: If $F$ is a vector subspace of a separable vector space $E$, then $F$ is also separable.

By example, I need this to use in another problem, like show that $F=S(A)=\{\tau\in A':\tau\geqslant0\mbox{ and }\|\tau\|\leqslant1\}$ is separable in weak-$*$ topology, where $A$ is vector space, $A'$ is dual space of $A$ and $E=A'$.

But, furthermore, I want know if a topological vector space $E$ (topology compatible with the sum and scalar product) always have the propriety that  $S\subset E$, $S$ a any subset, is separable if $E$ is separable.

Comment: This is true for metric spaces.  In metric space, separable is equivalent to second-countable; that property passes to subsets.

Comment: It works if $E$ is second countable (a strictly stronger condition than separability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is false:

Let $E := \mathbb R^{\omega_1}$ (with componentwise addition and scalar multiplication and product topology).
Of course, $E$ is a topological vectorspace. Moreover, it is well-known that $E$ is separable (Engelking, General topology, 2.3.16). 
For an element $\xi = (x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \omega_1}$ let
supp$(\xi) := \{\alpha: x_\alpha \neq 0\}$ be the support of $\xi$.
Then $F := \{\xi: \text{supp} (\xi) \text{ is finite} \}$ is a vector subspace of $E$, which is not separable: 
If $D \subset F$ is countable, then $\bigcup_{\xi \in D} \text{supp} (\xi)$ is countable, and therefore $D$ is not dense in $F$.

Comment: What is "$x_\alpha<>0$"?

Comment: @Kempa: sorry, accidentally I took over the notation from programming. It means $\neq 0$. Corrected.